# Unable to locate the model you have specified error in Codeigniter 3 and go daddy subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I am able to open the base url which displays the login view but when i submit the form to admin controller which should load model and call method to do authentication I get error "Unable to locate model: Admin_model".

I have deployed the code on godaddy subdomain and my htaccess file looks like following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/SYSTEM.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

It seems that this is a htaccess issue because models seems to load perfectly on localhost.

Comment: Can you confirm that your model file name is ucfirst (Uppercase for the first letter) ?

Comment: I changed the model file name from admin_model to Admin_model and it worked without any issue. Thanks for that. Although now my view is not getting loaded. It says "Unable to load the requested file: templates\sub_header.php". Do you know what's missing ? because my view file is there inside the templates folder and load the same through $this->load->view('templates/sub_header.php')

Comment: Remove the `.php` from `sub_header` in the load function => `$this->load->view('templates/sub_header')`. If if doesn't work, then I don't know, I need more info. You should open a new question and provide your controller's code.

Comment: remove ".php"  AND update line with 

$this->load->view('templates/sub_header')

Comment: I am sorry it was a typo. My controller code is $this->load->view('templates/sub_header') no .php still it is not working.

Comment: Since you don't have `NC` flag in `RewriteRule`, `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/SYSTEM.*` should probably be `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments : Your controller's file name must start with an uppercase. 
See http://codeigniter.com/userguide3/changelog.html

> changed filenaming convention (class file names now must be Ucfirst
>   and everything else in lowercase).